# Two groups of Buttons but with same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two groups of two buttons (status). If you click on Complete or On Hold it will change the background color of the button. I am using same class name for all the buttons but each group of buttons have data attribute `data-section='Park One'` and `data-section='Park Two'`

See working example: http://jsfiddle.net/1d40qhyx/

I am using `$.each()` function to detect the section, remove all the background and add the background-color on selected button. Is the code well coded or what can be improved?

Jquery:

```
$(".updateStatus").click(function () {

    var buttonValue = $(this).val();
    var section = $(this).data("section");

    var cssClass = (buttonValue === "complete") ? 'green' : 'orange';

    $('.updateStatus').each(function () {
        if ($(this).data("section") == section) {

            $(this).removeClass("green orange");

            if ($(this).val() == buttonValue) {
                $(this).addClass(cssClass);
            }
        }
    })

});
```

HTML

```
<h2>Park One</h2>

<button class="updateStatus" value="complete" data-section='Park One'>Complete</button>
<button class="updateStatus" value="on hold" data-section='Park One'>On Hold</button>

<h2>Park Two</h2>

<button class="updateStatus" value="complete" data-section='Park Two'>Complete</button>
<button class="updateStatus" value="on hold" data-section='Park Two'>On Hold</button>
```

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for this.

Comment: If your `section` can not group together,you can use your code ,but if can group,why don't you set `div` container to group them by same section?

Comment: @SkyFang I wish I have thought of that, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `event delegation` to use only a single listener rather than binding the click event to every of the elements with class `updateStatus`.
This should be more performant:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="section">
        <h2>Park One</h2>

        <button class="updateStatus" value="complete" data-section='Park One'>Complete</button>
        <button class="updateStatus" value="on hold" data-section='Park One'>On Hold</button>
    </div>
    <div class="section">    
        <h2>Park Two</h2>

        <button class="updateStatus" value="complete" data-section='Park Two'>Complete</button>
        <button class="updateStatus" value="on hold" data-section='Park Two'>On Hold</button>
    </div>
</div>

$("#wrapper").on("click", ".updateStatus", function(){ 
    var $siblings = $(this).siblings(); 
    var cssClass = ($(this).val() === "complete") ? 'green' : 'orange'; 
    $siblings.removeClass("green orange"); 
    $(this).addClass(cssClass); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1d40qhyx/2/

Comment: It selects the `sibling` elements of the currently selected element. Ie. the elements that are at the same level relative to the parent element.